# Shorten the Recorded Macro shortcut in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, keyboard-shortcuts

I have recorded a few macros in Google Sheet and added ShortCut key to each of the recorded macro. e.g. "Ctrl + Alt + Shift + NumericNo"

Is there anyway for me to 'shorten' the ShortCut from "Ctrl + Alt + Shift + NumericNo" to perhaps just "Ctrl + NumericNo" or "Alt + NumericNo"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal shortcut for macro is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + **Number**. Most keyboard shortcuts are already bound to the browser
or the system itself.

Example is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Number - This will switch to another tab.

Alternative for this is to click the macro by going to **Tools -> Macro -> click the function name**.

**References:**

- [Google Sheets Macros](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/macros)
- [Chrome keyboard shortcuts](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#zippy=%2Cgoogle-chrome-feature-shortcuts%2Ctab-and-window-shortcuts)